# jQuery animation weird right position?

Tags: jquery

I`m working on a new project and this time I want to login, when you click op Log in the login form fades away, and the header slide up to 45 pixels height. But now, the #slideUp div (the container) should slide up to 0 height but for some reason the div goes to the right?

[image: show image]

Script:

```
RekenTalent.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', 'userInfo', '$window', function($scope, $location, userInfo, $window){
    $scope.userInfo = userInfo.query();
    if($scope.userInfo.loggedIn) { $location.path('./homepage') }

    $scope.login = function() {
        $("#loginFrm").fadeOut(function() {
            $("header").animate({'height': 45});
            $("#slideUp").animate({'height': 0}, 1500, function() {
                $window.location.href = './#/homepage';
            });
        });
    }
}]);
```

Demo URL; http://dylaan.nl/rekentalent/#/

Answer (score 0):

you have a div `#logo` which has css `float:left`..

float is the reason for this behavior.. when you set float it floats on the page.. it doesn't come under its actual parent any more.. when you fadeout the parent, you are expecting this particular element also to fadeout along with the parent.. but it doesn't